# Powershell Detection Method - File path exists, and if so check filesize

Tags: powershell, sccm

I've got into a bit of a rut with this and I'm hoping someone can help me nail it:

I've been tasked with dropping a custom settings file into the roaming profile of the logged on user of all workstations.
The file would need to deployed if one of the 2 conditions are correct:

1. The file is not there.
2. The size of the file is smaller than that which is being deployed.

The deployment method is good, but the detection method is giving me a headache.

[Andy Dawson's blog](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/adawson/2020/05/11/deploying-files-to-the-logged-in-users-profile-using-configuration-manager/) got me most of the way there, it's the file size (length) bit that's not working for me.

**So, my first script went like this**:

Part 1: Get logged on user

```
Function CurrentUser {
     $LoggedInUser = get-wmiobject win32_computersystem | select username
     $LoggedInUser = [string]$LoggedInUser
     $LoggedInUser = $LoggedInUser.split(“=”)
     $LoggedInUser = $LoggedInUser[1]
     $LoggedInUser = $LoggedInUser.split(“}”)
     $LoggedInUser = $LoggedInUser[0]
     $LoggedInUser = $LoggedInUser.split(“\”)
     $LoggedInUser = $LoggedInUser[1]
     Return $LoggedInUser
}
```

Part 2: Assign User Path and Targetfile variables

```
$user = CurrentUser
$path = C:\Users\"+$user+"\AppData\Roaming\folder\folder\settings.cfg"
$targetfile = Get-Item $path
```

Part 3: Detect path exists and check filesize

```
if (( Test-Path $targetfile) -and ((Get-Item $targetfile).length -ge 26831))
{
Write-Host "installed"
}
else
{
Write-Host "NOT installed"
}
```

This works if **condition 1** is satisfied, but if not the detection method would fail because `$path` variable and therefore `$targetfile` could not be populated.

I was using the `$targetfile` variable because other methods of getting .length seemed to be returning the character count (therefore string length) rather than the intended file size value.

Back to the drawing board. It seems I need to only commence with the rest of the script, assigning the is Condition 1 is NOT satisfied, so...

**...My second (current) script goes like this:**

Part 1: Get logged on user
`UNCHANGED THIS BIT'S FINE, BECAUSE IS STOLE IT :)`

Part 2: Assign User and Userpath variables (simplified as this one will always be found)

```
$user = CurrentUser
$Userpath = "C:\Users\"+$user
```

Part 3: If path is NOT there state exists and check filesize

```
if (-not (Test-Path "$Userpath\AppData\Roaming\folder\folder\settings.cfg"))
{
Write-Host "NOT installed"
}
elseif.....
```

...and this is where the rut sets in! I want the second check to be along the lines of `((Get-Item $targetfile).length -ge 26831))` as before but I just can't seem to get the syntax/logic right here.

Any help greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: One less bracket on the right, and `-le` for the shorter file, should do. Or `-lt` in case you need file size to be strictly *L*ess *T*han your value.

Comment: Thanks, although if you're referring to the ```((Get-Item $targetfile).length -ge 26831))`` snippet at the end of post, that was actually a typo on my part, and just an example. I'll update the post accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I can't see how to edit the post...so guess I'll leave it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to test whether the file *doesn't exist* OR is to small:

```
if(-not(Test-Path $targetFile) -or (Get-Item $targetFile).Length -lt $newFileSize){
  # File either doesn't exist or is incomplete - go ahead and copy the new config file to $targetFile
  Copy-Item .\path\to\reference\config.cfg -Destination $targetFile -Force
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias. However, problem I've been having is how/when to assign the $targetfile variable. If I do it because the IF conditional section starts the detection method fails due to a ```Get-Item : Cannot find path``` error.

Comment: This is why it seems I had to abandon setting the variable until the script confirms it exists with the ```if (-not (Test-Path "$Userpath\AppData\Roaming\folder\folder\settings.cfg"))``` line

Comment: Did you try? :-) My answer solves that already - the right-hand expression of the `-or` operation only executes when the left-hand expression fails, so `Get-Item $targetFile` only ever executes when the file _does exist_.

Comment: @Jimbobbily You want `$targetFile = "$user\AppData\Roaming\folder\folder\settings.cfg"` - we just want to store _the file path_, nothing else

Comment: I have tested it. It's the variable setting that I'm not getting here

```
$user = CurrentUser
$Userpath = "C:\Users\"+$user
$targetFile = Get-Item "$user\AppData\Roaming\folder\folder\settings.cfg"

if(-not(Test-Path $targetFile) -or (Get-Item $targetFile).Length -lt 26830)
{
Write-Host "NOT installed"
}
else
{
}
```

This ends with the "Get-Item : Cannot find path" error. This is at the first Get-Item cmdlet

Comment: Again, don't attempt to call `Get-Item` _before_ you've validated the file is there. Store the string containing the file path, nothing else.

Comment: AH, hang on....I see what you're getting at. Although this presents another issue as $targetFile.length value is now 46, which is the string length

Comment: Which is why we call `(Get-Item $targetFile).Length` after validating that `Test-Path` doesn't fail ;)

Comment: Thanks Mathias, got it working as intended now